# Referrer issues when using POST from HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: node.js, http, nginx, https, cross-domain

I'm facing an issue when I moved my current app to `https` protocols & certificates.

The problem is that I cannot make any API calls anymore. I have `CORS` enabled in my `nodeJs` API but I cannot pass any call.

I've tried even to change the `API` hostname to `https://` instead of `http://`

If I use `http://api.site.xyz` I get `Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade`

If I use `https://api.site.xyz` I get `Referrer Policy:strict-origin-when-cross-origin`

The origin in both cases is `https://site.xyz` and on the server I am using `nginx`

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: And if you type in `https://api.site.xyz` in your browser you don't get redirected to `http://api.site.xyz` or something?

Comment: no, it's going to the website actually, it asks for the confirmation of potential warning and it goes to `https://site.xyz`, on the address bar it remains `https://api.site.xyz` but it renders the website

Comment: "it asks for the confirmation of potential warning" could that be the reason its not working? (like your browser did not allow the request because it did not trust the ssl certificate?)

Comment: the API does not have a certificate, it's `http` protocol. Only the website has the SSL certificate

Comment: I think its best you make the api https as well.